# React Axios : Issue with Fetching Data and Passing Company ID Value

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a React component where I am using Axios to fetch user master data within a useEffect hook. The initial state of UserMasterDataGlobal is an empty array, and after fetching the data, the state is updated. However, there is an issue with the asynchronous nature of the useEffect, resulting in the UserMasterDataGlobal array being initially empty.

Later in the component, I make a second Axios request to fetch route data using the CompanyId value from UserMasterDataGlobal. Due to the initial empty state, the CompanyId value is not passed correctly in the initial request.

I have attempted to structure my component with a useEffect hook to fetch user master data and update the state accordingly. However, since the Axios request is asynchronous, the UserMasterDataGlobal array is initially empty, causing issues when passing the CompanyId value in the subsequent Axios request.

I am expecting guidance on how to ensure that the second Axios request is made only after the UserMasterDataGlobal array is populated with values. Additionally, please note that I am relatively new to React, so any explanation in simpler terms or beginner-friendly suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useNavigate, generatePath, Link, BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Navbar, Nav, NavDropdown } from 'react-bootstrap';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import axios from 'axios';
import Swal from 'sweetalert2';
import withReactContent from 'sweetalert2-react-content';
import DataTable from 'react-data-table-component';
import { useParams } from 'react-router';

function CustomerMaster() {
  
  const usernameglobal = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('username'));
  const usertimestampglobal = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('usertimestamp'));

  const navigate = useNavigate();
  // const usernameglobal='';
  
  const Redirectif = () => {
    useEffect(() => {
      if (usernameglobal == null) {
        navigate('/LoginPage');
      }
    }, [usernameglobal, navigate]);
  } 

  try {
    if (usertimestampglobal != null) {
      const parsedTimestamp = parseInt(usertimestampglobal, 10);
      const currentTime = new Date().getTime();
      const twelveHoursAgo = currentTime - (12 * 60 * 60 * 1000); // 12 hours in milliseconds

      if (parsedTimestamp < twelveHoursAgo) {
        localStorage.removeItem('usertimestamp');
        localStorage.removeItem('username');
        Redirectif();
      }
    }
  }
  catch {
    
  }
  
  if(usernameglobal == null){
    Redirectif();
  }
  else{
    //2) using axios
    // Getusermasterglobaldata();
  }
  // console.log(UserMasterDataGlobal);
  
  const [UserMasterDataGlobal, setUserMasterDataGlobal] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    // Fetch data from the specified URL
    axios.get('http://localhost/api_link/codeigniter_part/public/UserMaster/getdatabyusername?username='+usernameglobal)

        .then((response) => {
          setUserMasterDataGlobal(response.data.UserMasterDataGlobal);
        })
        .catch((error) => console.error('Error fetching data:', error));
  }, []);

  const [RouteMasterData, setRouteMasterData] = useState([]);
  //2) using axios
  
  useEffect(() => {
  // Fetch data from the specified URL
  axios.get("http://localhost/api_link/codeigniter_part/public/RouteMaster?CompanyId="+UserMasterDataGlobal?.[0]?.CompanyId)

    .then((response) => {
        // Access the response data directly using response.data
        setRouteMasterData(response.data.RouteMasterData);
      })
      .catch((error) => console.error('Error fetching data:', error));
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To handle the asynchronous nature of the Axios request and ensure that the second request is executed only after the UserMasterDataGlobal array is populated.
you can also use conditional exectution in useEffect rendering.

like check below code

```html
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import axios from 'axios';

function CustomerMaster() {
  const usernameglobal = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('username'));
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  
  const Redirectif = () => {
    useEffect(() => {
      if (usernameglobal == null) {
        navigate('/LoginPage');
      }
    }, [usernameglobal, navigate]);
  }

  const [UserMasterDataGlobal, setUserMasterDataGlobal] = useState([]);
  const [RouteMasterData, setRouteMasterData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get(`http://localhost/api_link/codeigniter_part/public/UserMaster/getdatabyusername?username=${usernameglobal}`)
      .then((response) => {
        setUserMasterDataGlobal(response.data.UserMasterDataGlobal);
      })
      .catch((error) => console.error('Error fetching user master data:', error));
  }, [usernameglobal]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (UserMasterDataGlobal.length > 0) {
      axios.get(`http://localhost/api_link/codeigniter_part/public/RouteMaster?CompanyId=${UserMasterDataGlobal[0]?.CompanyId}`)
        .then((response) => {
          setRouteMasterData(response.data.RouteMasterData);
        })
        .catch((error) => console.error('Error fetching route data:', error));
    }
  }, [UserMasterDataGlobal]);

  if (usernameglobal == null) {
    Redirectif();
    return null; 
  }

  return (
    <div>
    <p> hello 123</p>
    </div>
  );
}

export default CustomerMaster;
```

Comment: Thanks, Vijay! My problem has been resolved. Initially, the array was coming as null, causing the CompanyId value in the UserMasterGlobal array to be undefined. I have now added an if statement to check if the UserMasterGlobal array is not null before proceeding with the code. This has successfully resolved my issue.